# What approaches are standard for 'healthcheck' monitoring of frontends?

Tags: monitoring

A problem I'm currently solving is that at a glance I want to see the status of various services, including both frontends and backends, across dev, test and prod environments.

That is, I want to see:

- Is the service running?
- What version of the service is running?

  - ie. A semvar
  - Latest commit hash
- What features is this service running? (eg. the sem ver of key dependencies)

It occurs to me that I can expose this information via:

- A `/healthcheck` endpoint for a REST API
- In either a meta tag or a script tag in the document head for a frontend.

That is - I poll each of my frontends say every minute, and retrieve the information about them, and display on my dashboard.

This [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/249701/is-it-safe-to-expose-a-commit-hash-on-a-public-healthcheck-endpoint) addresses the security concerns around that (leaking information) - but presumably any concerns can be alleviated by hashing the information with public key + a salt.

My question is - I feel like this must be a fairly standard kind of problem mature organisations solve - what is the standard solution? Is it out of the box tooling? Are they putting info in a script tag? Not putting that data on the FE at all - and instead looking at deploy logs?

Where I'm at is that I don't want to go reinventing the wheel - but at the same time, putting this info into a metatag doesn't sound especially cumbersome.

Comment: Are you using TLS in communication with the front end?
Are you concerned about your authenticated users seeing the healthcheck information?
Are you unable to require a specific authenticated role or claim to show the healthcheck info? There are a lot of site monitoring tools out there, with their own snippets and recipes.

Comment: To be clear the issue isn't about the security part specifically - it's about generally how do you go about seeing information about 'what version of a service is deployed, what features does it have' etc.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should distinguish between healthcheck for automatic monitoring, and version information.

An endpoint that can be used to check whether the service is running and considers itself healthy can be public, you don't disclose any dangerous information.

On the other hand, information about the current version, uptime, resource consumption etc. should only be accessible to authorized clients. That's not advocating security by obscurity but just keeping internal information private.